# Add quarterly dummy to ARIMA model

Tags: r, dummy-variable, arima

My data is a time series.

```
y <- ts(datafile[,"y"], start=1960, frequency=4, end=2010)
```

I want to include quarterly dummies in my forecasting ARIMA model. Is that possible? If so, what's the command for it? I can't seem to find one which allows me to merge the ARIMA model with the quarterly dummy variable.

So my ARIMA model is:

```
fit_y <- arima(y, order=c(2,1,2), method="ML")
```

I know how to fit seasonal ARs into the model:

```
fit_y <- arima(y, order=c(2,1,2), seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,1), period=4), method="ML")
```

Is there a way to include a quarterly dummy variable? I've created the dummy variables - *manually* - through excel and titled them Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, with the following specification so that R reads them as a time series variable:

```
Q1 <- ts(datafile[,"Q1"], start=1960, frequency=4, end=2010)
Q2 <- ts(datafile[,"Q2"], start=1960, frequency=4, end=2010)
Q3 <- ts(datafile[,"Q3"], start=1960, frequency=4, end=2010)
Q4 <- ts(datafile[,"Q4"], start=1960, frequency=4, end=2010)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the dummy variables to the arima model via the option xreg of `arima`.

```
y <- ts(datafile[,"y"], start=1960, frequency=4)
Q1 <- ts(rep(c(1,0,0,0),44), start=1960, frequency=4)
Q2 <- ts(rep(c(0,1,0,0),44), start=1960, frequency=4)
Q3 <- ts(rep(c(0,0,1,0),44), start=1960, frequency=4)
xreg <- cbind(Q1,Q2,Q3)

fit_y <- arima(y, order=c(2,1,2), method = "ML", xreg = xreg)
```

Note that (i) I didn't add the Q4, to avoid the dummy trap (see for example [question about dummy trap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144372/dummy-variable-trap) ), and (ii) that you can easily generate these Q1, Q2 and Q3 in R.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is kind of what I was looking for.

[edit: lol, didn't know pressing enter resulted in submitting the comment]



anyway, stupid question, I confess, but can you explain how I can generate these quarterly dummies in R? I've resorted to generating them manually from excel since I couldn't make sense of the stuff I've read online.


Thank you!

Comment: Well, you can generate Q1 via Q1 <- ts(rep(c(1,0,0,0),44), start=1960, frequency=4). You see?

Comment: thank you for this. Quick - and rather stupid - question. What does the 44 represent?

Comment: Also, since you've yet to reply, let me take this opportunity to add on another (stupid) question. Is there any way to generate the output of the ARIMA model with p-values and the stars (like how it is for a normal lm( y~x) type of output? When I summary() a lm(y~x), it shows me the coefficient estimate, SE and t-val and p-values, but when i summary an ARIMA output, it just shows me the coefficient estimates and SE.

Comment: Okay nevermind. I figured out what the 44 is. It's the number of years/repetitions I need for the dummy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the xreg argument in arima? xreg, external regressors, will allow you to include dummy variables in your arima. I usually create a matrix for my xreg which will include all my dummy variables. Below is an example of how I would do it for daily dummy variables.

```
dfTs$wday <- wday(dfTs$date)
xreg <- cbind(wday=model.matrix(~as.factor(dfTs$wday)))
xreg <- xreg[,-1] # drop intercept
colnames(xreg) <- c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat")
fit <- arima(dfTs, order = c(2,1,2),
               seasonal = list(order = c(0,1,1), period = 4),
               method = "ML", xreg = xreg)
```